# How to dynamically set default value in WTForms RadioField?

Tags: python, forms, flask, default, wtforms

I'm building a website with the Python [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework in which I use [WTForms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/). In one form I've got a [RadioField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=radiofield#wtforms.fields.RadioField) defined as follows:

```
display = RadioField('display', default='ONE')
```

This does not have any choices defined, because I do that lateron (which works perfectly fine):

```
myForm = MyForm()
myForm.display.choices = [('ONE', 'one'), ('TWO', 'two')]  # This works fine
```

I now want to set the default value for the RadioField *after* I set the choices for it. So I tried removing the default value from the definition (I'm not sure if `'ONE'` is always an available choice) and I create the default value after I create the choices like I do above:

```
myForm.display.default = 'ONE'
```

Unfortunately this has no effect at all. If I set it manually in the Field definition like I do before it works fine, but not if I set it dynamically after I created the choices.

Does anybody know how I can dynamically set the default value for a RadioField in WTForms? All tips are welcome!

Comment: You can pass default values in form constructor so you could 1st obtain the choices and then pass default choice to the MyForm constructor: MyForm(display='ONE')

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to run `myForm.process()` after adding the choices and setting the `default` property:

```
myForm = MyForm()
myForm.display.choices = [('ONE', 'one'), ('TWO', 'two')]
myForm.display.default = 'ONE'
myForm.process() # process choices & default
```

This is because the `default` is propagated to the field value (and, in the case of `RadioField`, the `checked` property) in the `process` method, which is called in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the comment by Bartosz Grzybowski, you can pass defaults as a constructor:

```py
class MyForm(Form):
    display = RadioField('display', default='ONE')

# Overwrite the default given in the field definition
myForm = MyForm(display='TWO')
```

This is because WTForms uses [`kwargs` to provide field data](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/e22b0863023f44ddc96ff5b11d78dc26f52a012f/src/wtforms/form.py#L123)