# Prepopulate WTForms radio field with info from view

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Using flask and WTForms. I am trying to combine my edit and create forms for posts. When a user clicks edit, the view checks if there is a post id passed, if there is it grabs the current info for that post and populates the form in the template. I can get this to work for every field but the 'main_post' field which is radio buttons.

View:

```
    @app.route('/posts-update' , methods=['POST','GET'])
    @login_required
    def posts_update():
        form = forms.Post()
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['id']:
            post = Post.query.filter_by(id=request.form['id']).first()
            form.title.data = post.title
            form.body.data = post.body

            # Works for all but main_post

            form.main_post.data = post.main_post

            # Also tried this and it didn't work
            # form = forms.Post(obj=post)
        else:
            post = False
            # form = forms.Post()
        return render_template('post_update.html', post=post, form=form)
```

Form:

```
    #post create and update
    class Post(Form):
        title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
        body = TextAreaField('Body', validators=[DataRequired()])
        main_post = RadioField('Make Main Post', choices=[('1', 'yes'), ('0', 'no')], validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Template:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="id" {% if post.id %}value="{{ post.id }}"{% endif %}>
    {{ form.title.label }} : {{ form.title }} <br/>
    {{ form.body.label }} : {{ form.body }} <br/>
    {{ form.main_post.label }} : {{ form.main_post }} <br/>
     <button class="button postfix"  type="submit">{% if post == False %}Add{% else %}Update{% endif %}</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

A similar question was asked and answered here [How to dynamically set default value in WTForms RadioField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423495/how-to-dynamically-set-default-value-in-wtforms-radiofield)

You should be able to do this by setting the `default` value and then running `form.process()`.

```
form.main_post.default = post.main_post
form.process()
```