# Flask WTForms Dynamic Default Value

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to have a dynamic default value for a form. This will be whatever was inputted last time it was used.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34820107/11411461) that says to modify the default value after creation and then use the process() method. This works in updating it (I see the default displayed on the web page), but I get an error when the form submits saying *The CSRF token is missing.* In chrome devtools I see that the form has a `input_id= 'csrf_token'` and a value so not sure what is happening?

```
class weight(FlaskForm):
    weight =  StringField('Enter your weight', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

```
last_weight = get_last_weight() # query database function, returns float (e.g 85.4)
form = weight()
form.weight.default = last_weight
form.process()
```

A related question, is this the best way to set a dynamic default? I tried

```
StringField('Enter your weight', validators=[DataRequired()], default=get_last_weight())
```

as the docs say

> default – The default value to assign to the field, if no form or object input is provided. May be a callable.

so I think the function is a callable (tell me if I'm wrong!) but I get an error saying that the function is being used outside of the application context, so I think the function is being called too early. It seems like this would be a common task so guessing I have missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `flash-message` when you tagged with Adobes `flash`? I've edited it with `flask` for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I like to handle dynamic form building

```
def buildWeightForm(last_weight):
    class weight(FlaskForm):
        weight = StringField('Enter your weight', default=last_weight, validators=[DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')
    return weight()
```

For your 2nd question, if you're getting an error doing this

```
StringField('Enter your weight', validators=[DataRequired()], default=get_last_weight())
```

Try the following (removing your parentheses from your function call):

```
StringField('Enter your weight', validators=[DataRequired()], default=get_last_weight)
```